# Own implementation of MaybeT lift

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement:

```
instance MonadTrans MaybeT where
    lift m = m >>= \a -> MaybeT $ return (Just a)
```

And it gets compiler error:

```
    Could not deduce (m ~ MaybeT m)
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 lift :: Monad m => m a -> MaybeT m a
      at MaybeTrans.hs:16:9-53
      `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for lift :: Monad m => m a -> MaybeT m a

    Expected type: MaybeT m a
      Actual type: m a
    In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `m'
    In the expression: m >>= \ a -> MaybeT $ return (Just a)
    In an equation for `lift':
        lift m = m >>= \ a -> MaybeT $ return (Just a)
```

I cannot understand where I made a mistake.
Please help me ;)

Comment: `lift` is `lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a` in your case `MaybeT ~ t` so it has to work for **all** Monads `m` - if you want to cheat you can look at the source of `MaybeT` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specialise the type of `lift` to your `MaybeT` type you have:

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }

lift :: Monad m => m a -> MaybeT m a
```

The type of `>>=` is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` so in your implementation:

```
lift m = m >>= \a -> MaybeT $ return (Just a)
```

you need to return a value of type `m b` while you return a value of type `MaybeT m b`, hence the error.

You now have two problems. The first is you need to move the application of `MaybeT` outside the application of `>>=`. The second is you need to construct a value of `m (Maybe a)` from the lamba passed to `>>=` i.e.

```
lift x = MaybeT $ x >>= \a -> return (Just a)
```

or simply:

```
lift x = MaybeT $ fmap Just x
```